# Does a matrix product have an upper bound on the largest coefficient?

Tags: probability-distributions, approximation-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ random matrices. Matrix $A$ has coefficients taken from a normal distribution $ \mathcal{N}(\mu_A,\sigma_A)$, and matrix $B$ has coefficients taken from $ \mathcal{N}(\mu_B,\sigma_B)$. Can we identify a non-trivial upper bound for the expected maximum coefficient of the product $A\cdot B$?

Comment: What would count as "trivial"?  That is, what's the "trivial" upper bound that you want to improve on?

Comment: A trivial upper bound would be for example the larget absolute cofficient value in A multiplied by the largest absolute cofficient value in B multiplied by n